# Select value from list in Python toolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-toolbox

within a Python toolbox in ArcGIS 10.2 I fill a parameter with a list. `parameters[0].filter.list = myList` It is essentialy a list of strings and will give the user a range of predefined years.
Later I check a file name if it holds information of a year. In case there is a year to be extracted from the name I want the value in the list defined for `parameters[0]` to be selected.

If I use SetParameterAsText() then I will overwrite my list of years, and cut my user short on the possibility to correct the year in case the extracted year is not the one the user is focusing on.

Since the year is anyway already part of the list... is there a way to say `parameters[0].SelectValue()` or `parameters[0].SelectListItem()` to get a visual confirmation for the user?

I hope it is understandable what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish and how your user is interacting with the list of years (I'm guessing they are choosing a value from the list on the form, an image of the form might help) and how you expect them to get visual confirmation of the file name year? Do you want to select the file name year from the list on the form by default unless the user changes it?

Comment: Alright, when the tool is called and the form initiated, the list is created upfront.

    lst_years = []
    int_year = datetime.datetime.today().year
    for in_year in range(1980, int_year+1):
        lst_years.append(str(in_year))

As soon as the user specifies a featureclass in the form, the name is analysed if there is a piece in it that can be turned into a datetime object and will be returned as a string. Let's say it's 2000. Then 2000 can be found in the pre-made list ans inside the form it should be selected. If that's not what the user wants, he still should be able to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the year you should be able to just assign it to 
parameters[0].value. Also there is an example that may be useful to you [here.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Defining_parameters_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000028000000/) Look at the first example from the top of the page where it writes param1.value = 'sinuosity'.

Comment: Nice try, but unfortunately I am getting an error of **NoneType object is not callable**. Below the way I define the parameter.  
    # Define calculation year  
    int_today = datetime.datetime.today().year  
    in_int_year = arcpy.Parameter(  
        displayName="Calculation Year",  
        name="str_years",  
        datatype="GPLong",  
        parameterType="Required",  
        direction="Input")  
    in_int_year.filter.type = "Range"  
    in_int_year.filter.list = [1980, int_today+1]

Comment: Sorry for the mess with the code but the formating simply does not do what it should do in the comments.

Comment: In the end it was all much more easy... than I thought.
I simply wanted to assign the value by `parameters[1].value(whatSoEver)`instead of `parameters[1].value = whatSoEver`

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be where you are trying to set the value, for a pyt I've had more luck doing this in updateParameters, after the FC gets its value rather than using a filter in the getParameterInfo. With parameters[0] as the FC and parameters[1] as your date value:

```
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    if parameters[0].altered
    #set your yearValue according to parameters[0]
    #you'll also either set int_today here or need to pull that in from where you set it
         parameters[1].filter.type = "Range"
         parameters[1].filter.list = [yearValue, int_today+1]
```

I believe that will give the user the option to select the generated date and no other options from the list, I haven't tried to see what happens when they want to change it. The other options would be to filter by the original list but instead setting the desired value as the default using [defaultEnvironmentName](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Defining_parameters_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000028000000/) but i've never tried doing that in the updateparameters.